# Can I split system use case diagram into smaller pieces?

Tags: uml, modeling, use-case

I have a system which can be split into modules: User, Announcements, Stories, Meetings and News. Each module has about 6 use cases. Can I make one diagram per each module? If yes, do they differ in any way from all-in-one-diagram? And, should I make a diagram with all those modules represented in it?

I also found out a "package" concept. If I understood it right, I can use them as those modules. And then, on primary use case diagram, put all the packages together with associations to its actors. Each package has own use cases diagram with the same actors got from the whole application model. Am I right? So for the "modules" A, B, C and actors 1, 2 - I have one diagram with packages A, B, C and 1, 2 actors, and three use case diagrams for respectively A, B, C packages and its and only its actors (like, actor one uses package A, but not B, C, so he doesn't appear on them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do a diagram from each module and these diagrams might be different from an all-in-one diagram. 
The main difference between all these possible diagram is the context of the diagram. 
If you  made a diagram for the "Users" module, this latter will contain several uses cases associated to actor(s). By definition the actors are outside our system (i.e. your "User" module) and they could be human or system (e.g. your other modules). In an all-in-one diagram you would not be able to represent the fact that a given module is "used" by another which can be done if you model a use cases diagram for each module.
Hoping it helps,

Comment: It helps very much. Please, take a look on my updated question.

Comment: If I well understood your point, I agree with your package usage.

Comment: And how about subsystem instead of package?

Comment: What do you mean by "subsystem instead of package" ?
You might want to model your system and yours subsystem as a main package and sub packages or a main component and sub components, etc.

Comment: I end up with making Users, Announcements, Stories and so on, as `subsystem`s. Then, since application follows HMVC pattern, each `subsystem` is divided into `package`s.